# Prevent scp from overwriting existing files?

Tags: files, scp, file-copy, administration

Have been googling this for a while, and the problem is not so much of one where I trust my users to "do the right thing" and have them use rsync with various options to avoid overwriting files.  I actually need to somehow have scp not overwrite existing files... rsync is not an option because there will be those who will use scp... so I need to deal with that.

I think it possible to modify the sshd code, so there would be one potential avenue to solve this.

Other than that, has anyone else cracked this nut and what was done?  Wrappers?

Comment: So do you want to keep certain files from getting overwritten or prevent `scp` from _ever_ overwriting files?

Comment: A quicker/easier option might be to write a mini-wrapper around scp that will check for the existence of the file first and exit if it already exists and if it doesn't then it will proceed with the update. I could help with that if required.

Comment: Only certain files need to be protected.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple shell function (`bash` and `ksh93`) that wraps around `scp`. It will refuse to execute the real `scp` if the target file exists on the system.

```
function scp
{
    typeset argv="$@"
    typeset target="${argv[-1]}"

    if [[ -e "$target" ]]; then
        echo 'Target file exists, refusing to overwrite' >&2
        return 1
    fi

    command scp "$@"
}
```

The function picks out the target from the last command line argument, and then checks to see if it corresponds to an existing filename. If it does, it refuses to run `scp`, displaying a diagnostic message, and returns a non-zero exit status.

If there is no existing filename corresponding to the target, it goes ahead and calls the real `scp` with the original command line.

No attempt is made to distinguish between a transfer in one direction or the other. It will thus fail if there's a filename corresponding to the `user@hostname:file`-type format in the current directory.

If you have a list of protected filenames in a file (this should be a list of absolute pathnames, one per line, corresponding to the real path of each file as returned by the GNU coreutils utility `realpath`):

```
function scp
{
    typeset argv="$@"
    typeset target="${argv[-1]}"

    if grep -q -F -x "$( realpath "$target" )" protected_files.txt; then
        echo 'Target filename is protected, refusing to overwrite' >&2
        return 1
    fi

    command scp "$@"
}
```